# Why i get ORA-12504 error in my connection string?

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm beginner in oracle,want to connect oracle database with c# windows appliation
but why i try connect database i get this error:
[image]

my listener file is this:

```
MYLISTNER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-A5CFJSH)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_MYLISTNER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\BEHZAD-HUSH\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\BEHZAD-HUSH\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_MYLISTNER = C:\app\BEHZAD-HUSH
```

and my tnsnames file is:

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

What happen?How can i solve that?thanks.

my tns ping is:

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 02-NOV-2015 15:42:22

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\app\BEHZAD-HUSH\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = CLRExtProc) (PRESENTATION = RO)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
```

Comment: Where does that window you have screenshotted come from? if it is your application you need to at least post that code that is building the connect string.

Answer (score 0):

Server name should be from TNS (ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA), not localhost.

**EDIT:**

> TNS-12541: TNS:no listener

Check that tns listener is running.

```
CMD> lsnrctl
LSNRCTL> start
```

Before you start to develop application, you must first check database connection over tnsping/sqlplus. Only after you have successfully connected you can move forward.

If listener is curently runnig, you cant try to connect over tcp/ip, not over IPC (after changing tns connection string in tnsnames.ora) on this -

```
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
 (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = DESKTOP-A5CFJSH) (PORT = 1521)) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = CLRExtProc))
 )
```

Comment: thanks for answer,but i get this error:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

Comment: Add "tnsping ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA" output in your question.

Comment: please review my question

Comment: Always check the connection using a tnsping. If it gives an error then it makes no sense trying to connect in other applications.

Answer (score 0):

TNS is a real double-edged sword.  When it works, it works great, but if you don't have any control over the client machine where you are deploying an app, you may want to just skip it and connect directly.

Fortunately, Oracle came up with ezConnect, which dramatically simplifies connection strings.  It's essentially:

```
server/port:service name (or SID)
```

By explicitly specifying the elements normally encapsulated in TNSNAMEs, you eliminate any chances that the target machine has a different definition for that TNS name or worse, no definition at all.

Or, if you use the `Direct=true`, you can still bypass TNSnames and explicitly spell out the server, port and service name:

```
String conString = String.Format("Direct=true;Server={0};" +
    "Port={1};Service Name={2};User Id={3};Password={4};",
    "myhost.foo.bar", 1521, "oraprod", "scott", "tiger");
```

or using the SID (I can never remember which works, so I try both):

```
String conString = String.Format("Direct=true;Server={0};" +
    "Port={1};SID={2};User Id={3};Password={4};",
    "myhost.foo.bar", 1521, "oraprod", "scott", "tiger");
```

and then:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(constring);
conn.Open();
```

(with appropriate error trapping, of course).

That was more info than you asked for, but the bottom line is when you are establishing the connection, I would use this as the "Server Name" in your dialog:

```
DESKTOP-A5CFJSH:1521/CLRExtProc
```